# displaying only the workdays along with time in excel sheet

Tags: excel

I am looking for excel sheet help:
creation date + no of hrs = expected due date excluding weekends
eg., 11/24/2017 16:23 + 72 hrs = 11/29/2017 16:23

I tried couple of combination with workday() in excel but no luck. can someone help ?

Comment: _(sorry about that, I mis-read; I deleted my answer.)_  In your example you are using 72 hours, which is exactly 3 days.  Will you be adding partial days as well, like 70 hours?

Comment: There are still some caveats but if 70 hours needs to be added, or other amounts not divisible by 24, then you can do that with an adjusted version of my suggestion - see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

If you always have a number of hours that's divisible by 24 (i.e. a whole number of days) then this will work

`=WORKDAY(A2,B2/24)+MOD(A2,1)`

Assuming date/time in `A2` and hours to add in `B2`

The result of the `WORKDAY` function is always just a date, so the `MOD` part just adds the hours from `A2` to give you the same time in the result cell as the date/time cell

If the hours may not be divisible by `24` then you can try this version, assuming that any time on a working day is a valid result

`=WORKDAY(A2,MOD(A2,1)+B2/24)+MOD(A2+B2/24,1)`

Assumes that `A2` is a working day

Comment: @SP99 If that works OK for you can you consider accepting my answer - thanks

Comment: actually there is an issue, in many of excel cells it displays the exectly same value as A2. Which is wrong.                                                              
suppose in A2 if the value is "10-4-17 1:00" and I add 8 hours in that it should show me 10-4-17 9:00.

Comment: 11-1-17 18:38 + 16 hrs should show me 11-2-17 10:38 but in the result column i see "11-1-17 18:38".                                                                                     I am using the second version of your function

Comment: @SP99 Did you try the longer version I suggested? - that works for those two examples

Comment: yes there was a mistake at mind end i corrected it. Its working now. thanks a lot. Berry :)

Comment: Barry - one more help. I am getting my output all wrong.
creation date -  12/08/2017 21:38 + 16 hrs of weekdays, 2 PM to 11 PM = it should show 12/12/2017 17:38
Where the current formula is showing-12/11/17 13:38.                                           right now i am using =WORKDAY(E102,MOD(E102,1)+P102/24)+MOD(E102+P102/24,1) can you please help ?

Comment: @SP99 - OK, my original suggestion assumed 24 hours of working time each MF day, if you want to restrict to a specific period like 14:00 - 23:00 that can be done but two questions - For your example how do you get 12/12/2017 17:38? I'd expect the result to be 12/12/2017 19:38? In your example start time is a Friday at 21:38 so that's within your working day - would you always expect start time to be within the working day?

Comment: 1)Creation date-12/08/2017 21:38 and the work window is till 23:00 meaning 1: 22 hour on 12/08. out of 16 work hrs-1.22 hrs are gone = 14.78 hrs remaining to work on that issue within deadline                                                                                     2) excluding 12/09 and 12/10 weekend                                                        3) deduct 9 hrs on 12/11 -> 14.78 - 9 (2 Pm-11 Pm) = 5.78 hrs remaining                               4) deduct 5.78 from 9 = 3.22 hrs.so i should get 2Pm+3 hrs 22 min -> 12/11/2017 17:22

Comment: work can come on weekend too but the time one works on should be considered of weekdays alone, like issue came on saturday morning the clock doesnt start till monday 2 PM.

Comment: In terms of complexity this is a big jump from my original suggestion - see daddylonglegs suggestion here for adding work hours to a date/time which might not be during working hours: https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/1204157-due-date-calculation-by-taking-only-working-hours-and-days.html#post4759924